# jQuery $.proxy scope

Tags: jquery, oop, scope

I have the following code:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    $('#weight').click($.proxy(function(){
        this.changeWeight($('#weight').is(':checked'));
    },this));
    $('#produce').change($.proxy(function(){
        this.changeProduce();
    },this));
    $('.help-gtin').click($.proxy(function(){
        if ($('#help-gtin').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#help-gtin').slideDown();
        } else {
            $('#help-gtin').slideUp();
        }
        this.refreshGtin();
    },this);

    $('[name="order_production"]').click($.proxy(function(){
        this.changeProduction();
    },this));

},
```

How can I reduce this repetive code ***$.proxy call*** as all methods inside `bindEvents` will be need call in `this` scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that they're already [closures](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html), by setting a variable equal to `this` and then using that:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    var self = this; // <==== Set the variable

    $('#weight').click(function(){
        // v--- Use it (throughout)
        self.changeWeight($('#weight').is(':checked'));
    });
    $('#produce').change(function(){
        self.changeProduce();
    });
    $('.help-gtin').click(function(){
        if ($('#help-gtin').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#help-gtin').slideDown();
        } else {
            $('#help-gtin').slideUp();
        }
        self.refreshGtin();
    });

    $('[name="order_production"]').click(function(){
        self.changeProduction();
    });

},
```

All of the functions you define within `bindEvents` "close over" the context of the call to `bindEvents`, and have access to the local variables associated with that call. Unlike `this`, those variables don't change depending on how the functions are called.

This also has the advantage that you can use `this` within the event handlers with its jQuery meaning, the element on which you hooked the event (this saves your looking it up again, for instance within your `click` handler on `#weight`).